# MATLAB regexp skip if part of word

Tags: regex, matlab

Given the following example:

```
str = 'deriv*dot(N,iv)';
expr = 'iv';
idx = regexp(str,expr);
```

This returns idx with 4 and 13. How do I only find the 'iv' that is NOT part of a word?

I tried messing around with Lookaround Operators for expr, but could not get the result I desired. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It seems like Matlab has it's own word boundary escape sequence.](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42983)

```
expr = '\<iv\>';
```

That defines a word as anything that consists of letters, digits and underscores. If you want your own definition (i.e. letters only), then you need lookarounds:

```
expr = '(?<![a-zA-Z])expr(?![a-zA-Z])';
```